# Converting ADODB Loop into DAO

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ado, dao

Hi I've been developing a vba project with a lot of help from examples here. I'm trying to access a MS Access database from Excel VBA and import large data sets (500-100+ rows) per request.

Currently, the following loop works using ADODB however, the Range("").Copyfromrecordset line is taking very long roughly 7 seconds per request.

```
 Public Sub BC_Data()

Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection, rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strCon, SQL As String
Dim ID As Integer

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=...\Database.accdb;"

cn.Open strCon
    For i = 0 To n
        ID = Range("A2").Offset(i, 0).Value
        SQL = "SELECT [Sales] WHERE [ID] = " & ID & _
        " AND [Date] >= #" & [A1].Text & "# AND [Date] <= #" & _
        [B1].Text & "#;"
        rs.Open SQL, cn
        Range("C2").Offset(0, i).CopyFromRecordset rs
        rs.Close
    Next
cn.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

The SQL works fine and is just selecting each transaction for a given product ID and time period.

The reason I'm using this sort of loop is that the we only want the data for ~20 of the products at a time and they aren't necessarily in a sequence so the IDs could be 1,2,4, 7, 200, 205, 654 etc.

The IDs are stored in Column A and then the request loops through and pastes each new column in Columns C onwards.

I have 2 questions:

1. Will using a DAO connection instead of ADODB speed up this process? If so, how would I go about replicating this in DAO?
2. Is the method I'm using to loop through the IDs and then request an efficient one? Is there a faster method, maybe using a "For each" loop instead?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DAO might be a little faster, but not materially. Instead, use an IN clause in your SQL Statement so you only have to do it once.

```
Sub test()

    Dim vaIds As Variant
    Dim sSql As String

    vaIds = Split("1 2 4 7 200 205 654", Space(1))

    sSql = "SELECT [Sales] WHERE [ID] In(" & Join(vaIds, ",") & ")" & _
        " AND [Date] >= #" & [A1].Text & "# AND [Date] <= #" & _
        [B1].Text & "#;"

    Debug.Print sSql

End Sub
```